# facebook android allow permission window problem

Tags: android, facebook

I'm beginner with android and developing an application in android to connect to facebook and upload photo using the android facebook sdk.

Problem is when I login I'm getting an allow permission window. When I click `allow`, its not giving any action.

Any ideas on the problem?

Answer (score 1):

After you authorize Permissions on Facebook, Facebook will redirect your to a confirm url you told the system to redirect to. Please check if you pass that url after approval redirection in the `next` parameter (assuming you use webbased authentication)

I've done from a PHP server this way:

```
function promptForPermissions() {
    global $permissions;
    $gateway="http://www.facebook.com/connect/prompt_permissions.php";
    header("Location: ".$gateway."?api_key=".API_KEY."&ext_perm=".join(",",$permissions)."&next=".URL_AFTER_APPROVAL."&cancel=".URL_IF_CANCEL."&display=touch");
}
```

where the urls were having this format:

http://www.example.com/callback.php?permissionsApproved=1
http://www.example.com/callback.php?cancelled=1

Comment: Thanks for reply Pentium10, i wanted java code do have java code?